# Specify Deployment.template.json in IoT Edge Solution

Tags: visual-studio, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I have a few different "deployment.template.json" files in my IoT edge project. The project is part of Visual Studio 2017 solution with IoT Edge extension installed.

e.g.

```
deployment.template.json
deployment.template.testDevice1.json
deployment.template.testDevice2.json
deployment.template.debug.json
```

Is there a way to specify which deployment template to use when generating a deployment from the project with visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

In best practice, you should create multiple edge projects in Visual Studio.

For your scenario, you can create two edge project, and generate different deployment JSON file through context menu in different edge project.

[image: Multiple Edge Projects]